# Decode a YAML serialized object

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have serialized an object in YAML and send it to a remote worker.

The worker doesent have the object definition so i get a YAML::Object.

How can i access the field inside it?

A text field seems like that base64 encoded, how can i decode that? (no, decode64 not works).

Comment: You should provide an example.

Comment: a = Foo.new ; b=a.to_yaml ; c= Yaml::load(b) ; now i want to get c.bar

Comment: class foo
attr_accessor :foo

def initialize 
 @foo = 'test'
end
end

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the object as something "known between both sides" (like an openstruct or hash) or give the description to the client.

It would be interesting to have a serialization format that also serialized the class and its methods...I'll have to think about that one...

Answer (score 0):

try c["bar"]

you can also see all the provided keys using c.keys